# Why white line is visible after area addition and subtraction?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

Here is my Interface

```
package Tools;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL-PC
 */
public interface ToolsModel extends Serializable {

    public void setColor(Color color);

    public Color getColor();

    public void setVisible(boolean b);

    public boolean isVisible();

    public void setID(String id);

    public String getID();

    public ToolsModel getShape();

}
```

And i have done some creating irregular shape using this interface and from this interface and i want to Add.Subtract on interface and it's working fine but some white raised. 
Here is my code which is used to Add,Subtract on interface.

```
public void trimShade(ToolsModel toolsModel) {
        System.out.println("I am at TrimShade");
        Area area = new Area();
        for (ToolsModel model : getShadeList()) {
            if (model.equals(toolsModel) || model.getID().equals(toolsModel.getID())) {
                continue;
            }
            area.add(new Area((Shape)model));
            if (!area.isEmpty()) {
                ((Area) model).subtract(new Area((Shape)toolsModel));

            }
        }
    }
```

First we draw here the polygonal irregular shape and then After we draw next shape inside the first shape. 

 **Here is the output result:**

[image]

How to remove this white line  which raised after two area addition and subtraction. It is one the border of the second Area.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: i'm assuming you're drawing onto an image, if that's the case it might be worth checking that these constructions lines are drawn on the panel and not the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution and i fixed the problem when i comment the Anti aliasing and Quality render hints.

```
//g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
```